# Ending a process when a tcp connection is closed

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, process

I am developing a client-server application where whenever a new client connects to the server, the server spawns a new process using the `multiprocessing` module.  Its target function is a function where it takes the socket and does I/O.  The problem I have is once the TCP connection is closed between the client and the process on the server how/where do I put the .join() function call to end the child process?  Also do I need to do any waitpid in the parent process like in C?

Server code:

```
def new_client(conn_socket):
    while True:
        message = conn_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        conn_socket.send(message)  
        #just echo the message
        #how to check to see if the TCP connection is still alive?
        #put the .join() here??



def main():
    #create the socket
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

    #bind the socket to the local ip address on a specific port and listen
    server_port = 12000                               
    server_socket.bind(('',server_port))
    server_socket.listen(1)

    #enter in a loop to accept client connections
    while True:
        connection_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()       
        #create a new process with the new connection_socket
        new_process = Process(target = new_client, args = (connection_socket,))
        new_process.start()
        #put the .join() here or what??

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also for this setup would it be more beneficial to use threads in the `thread` module or stay with processes?  The server code is being developed for heavy usage on a server with "average" specs(how to optimize this setup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the return value of `recv`. If it returns zero then the connection is closed nicely, if negative then there was an error.

And the `join` call should be in the process that creates the sub-process. However, be carefull because `join` without argument will block the calling process until the sub-process is done. Put the processes in a list, and on regular intervals call `join` with a small timeout.

**Edit:** Simplest is to add, at the end of the infinite accept loop, to iterate over the list of processes, and check if it's `is_alive`. If not then call `join` and remove it from the list.

Something like:

```
all_processes = []
while True:
    connection_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()       
    #create a new process with the new connection_socket
    new_process = Process(target = new_client, args = (connection_socket,))
    new_process.start()

    # Add process to our list
    all_processes.append(new_process)

    # Join all dead processes
    for proc in all_processes:
        if not proc.is_alive():
            proc.join()
    # And remove them from the list
    all_processes = [proc for proc in all_processes if proc.is_alive()]
```

Note that purging of old processes will only happen if we get a new connection. This can take some time, depending on if you get new connections often or not. You could make the listening socket non-blocking and use e.g. [`select`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) with a timeout to know if there are new connections or not, and the purging will happen at more regular intervals even if there are no new connections.

Comment: I understand what you mean by putting the processes in a list, but what do you mean on a regular interval call join with a small timeout? Also, would this be a general way to handle sockets in python using processes and not threads?